# The task is to find a subsequence with maximum sum such that there should be no adjacent elements from the array in the subsequence

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, search, data-structures

It's showing the wrong answer. Can anybody please tell me which test case I am missing ?

**Without Adjacent**

Given an array arr[] of N positive integers. The task is to find a subsequence with maximum sum such that there should be no adjacent elements from the array in the subsequence.

Input:
First line of input contains number of testcases T. For each testcase, first line of input contains size of array N. Next line contains N elements of the array space seperated.

Output:
For each testcase, print the maximum sum of the subsequence.

Constraints:

`1 <= T <= 100`

`1 <= N <= 10^6`

`1 <= arr[i] <= 10^6`

Example:

Input:

```
2
3
1 2 3
3
1 20 3
```

Output:

```
4
20
```

Explanation:

Testcase 1: Elements 1 and 3 form a subsequence with maximum sum and no elements in the subsequence are adjacent in the array.

Testcase 2: Element 20 from the array forms a subsequence with maximum sum.

I tried using below test cases also

Input:

```
3
9
1 2 9 4 5 0 4 11 6
1
0
1
1
```

Output:

```
26
0
1
```

It worked fine but while submitting it was giving "wrong answer" I don't know for which test case it was talking about

Here is my solution:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        
        int arr[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
       
        int sum1,sum2,sum_even=0,sum_odd=0;
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i+=2)
            sum_even+=arr[i];
        for(int i=1;i<n;i+=2)
            sum_odd+=arr[i];
        
        if(n>=1)
            sum1 = arr[0];
        else
            sum1 = -1;
        
        if(n>=2)
            sum2 = arr[1];
        else
            sum2 = -1;   
            
        int new_sum,i;
        
        for(i=2; i<n; i+=2)
        {
            if((i+1)!=n && arr[i+1]>arr[i])
            {
                i++;
                sum1+=arr[i];
            }
            else if(i+1==n)
            {
                sum1+=arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                sum1+=arr[i];
            }
        }
        
        for(i=3; i<n; i+=2)
        {
            if((i+1)!=n && arr[i+1]>arr[i])
            {
                i++;
                sum2+=arr[i];
            }
            else if(i+1 ==n)
            {
                sum2+=arr[i];
            }
            else
            {
                sum2+=arr[i];
            }
        }
        
        int sum = sum1>sum2 ? sum1 : sum2;
        sum = sum>sum_odd ? sum : sum_odd;
        sum = sum>sum_even ? sum : sum_even;
      
        cout<<sum<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's your code that gives the wrong answer?

Comment: @cigien Sorry for that I forgot to put the code. Now can you please look at it again. Thank you

Comment: Usually, you are expected to figure out at least one test case for which the program fails. Have you written any of your own tests? Do they all pass?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you seem to made some guesses on the structure on any solution.
Your code is rather complex and it is difficult effectively to find a counter example by hand.
I made a random generation of arrays and compare your result with the optimal one.
I finally obtained this counter example : [14 18 8 19 22 1 20 23]. Your code gives a result of 64, while the optimum sum is equal to 67.

A simple optimum solution is to iteratively calculate two sums, both corresponding to a maximum up to the current index `i`,
the first sum (`sum0`) assuming current value `arr[i]` is not used, the second sum (`sum1`) assuming the current value `arr[i]` is used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int max_sum (const std::vector<int>& arr) {
    int sum0 = 0; 
    int sum1 = arr[0];
    int n = arr.size();
    
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int temp = sum0;
        sum0 = std::max (sum0, sum1);
        sum1 = temp + arr[i];
    }
    return std::max (sum0, sum1);
}

int main() {
    int t;
    std::cin >> t;
    while(t--) {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::vector<int> arr(n);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           std::cin >> arr[i];
        int sum = max_sum (arr);
        std::cout << sum << '\n';
    }
}
```