# Max Sub Array (non-adjacent)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm working on a HackerRank Max Array Sum problem. I see some simple and smart solutions but I wanna know why my code failing.

Here is my code. It takes next 4 elements from array and choose index0 or index1 and shift 2 or 3 elements.
if I can find max subset elements instead of sum of elements I can see my mistake.
[HackerRank Problem Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/max-array-sum/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=dynamic-programming)

```
def Calc(arr):

result = 0

i = 0
while i < len(arr):

    tempar = [i if i > 0 else 0 for i in arr[i:i+4]]

    if len(tempar) == 4:
        tmax = max(tempar[0] + tempar[2], tempar[0] + tempar[3], tempar[1] + tempar[3])

        if tempar[0] + tempar[2] == tmax or tempar[0] + tempar[3] == tmax:
            result += tempar[0]
            i += 2
        elif tempar[1] + tempar[3] == tmax:
            result += tempar[1]
            i+=3

    if len(tempar) == 3:
        if tempar[0] + tempar[2] > tempar[1]:
            result += tempar[0] + tempar[2]
        else:
            result += tempar[1]
        i+=3

    if len(tempar) == 2:
        result += max(tempar)
        i+=2
    
    if len(tempar) == 1:
        result += tempar[0]
        i+=1
return result


input()

ar = list(map(int, input().split()))
    
    
print(Calc(ar))
```

Comment: In such a situation, to find where the error is, you have first to find an input with a wrong output, and then to analyse tour algorithm/code with this input. I suspect here an algorithm problem. You will get more help with you could provide such a test case. Besides, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63826849/10553341), I proposed a very simple algorithm. But no python code!

Comment: What happens if `i + 4` is greater than the length of the array? Besides, I don't understand how you can make a decision for the range `[i:i+4]`, without knowing the values of the array just after.

Comment: @Damien First I try to find an useful input but hackerrank testcases have array 100000 long so i can't analyse. Second "[i:i+4]" python take care of it.

Comment: In such a situation, you have to generate your own short random inputs and check them. I didn't know for Python effectively!

Comment: @Damien thx for answers. Do u know a way to see elements in chosen subset so i can put them in a file and compare them with mine.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with *see elements in chosen subset*. If your algorithm is not correct, then I assume that performing your own tests with short sequences (length 5 or 6) is enough

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your algorithm and the problem carefully, so I can't say whether your algorithm is right or not.

But it seems that your code allows choosing an empty set when all elements are negative. (`tempar = [i if i > 0 else 0 for i in arr[i:i+4]]`)

For example, your program will output `0` for the input

```
5
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, the null set is a subset, and `sum=0` could be valid. But the site question is not clear about it.

Comment: "given [-2, 1, 3, -4, 5] we have the following possible subsets:

Subset      Sum
[-2, 3, 5]   6
[-2, 3]      1
[-2, -4]    -6
[-2, 5]      3
[1, -4]     -3
[1, 5]       6
[3, 5]       8"

Comment: @Damien It seems that a legal solution must have at least two elements in the HackerRank problem.

Comment: Effectively. It seems strange. It means that the algorithm that I mentioned in another post must be adapted (not too difficult). However, I suspect that the algorithm proposed by OP is not correct,  even without this constraint.

Comment: @Damien I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm doesn't work.
for simple input
5
-1 -1 3 -2 5

I suggest you use the following approach:

```
def Calc(arr):

result = 0
prev_result=0
is_last_included=False
i = 0
while i < len(arr):
    if arr[i] > 0:
        if is_last_included==False:
            prev_result=result
            result=result+arr[i]
            is_last_included=True
        elif (prev_result+arr[i])>result:
            temp=result
            result=prev_result+arr[i]
            prev_result=temp
            is_last_included=True
        else:
            prev_result=result
            is_last_included=False
    i=i+1
return result
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but why result of input 5 -1 -1 3 -2 5 is 10 instead of 13. Shouldn't it be 5 + 3+ 5